# Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'

Tags: angular

I have imported the Headers and i have included the object and url and headers. but it's showing error

> Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'

My code:

```
getContactData(aplhaNumericId:any) {
  let obj = {aplhaNumericId:aplhaNumericId};
  let headers=new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf=8');
  return this.http.post('http://ip/ex/api/api/JsonServices.php',JSON.stringify(obj),headers)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Pls mention you angular version and give us little more info.

Comment: sure, I am using angular 4

Comment: angular 4.3 + or below? are you using HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'; or old '@angular/http' ?

Comment: I am using angular-v4.2.4

Comment: I am using @angular/http

Comment: can u help me to resolve this request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `Headers` in `RequestOptions` before passing it to `post(...)`

```
return this.http.post('http://ip/ex/api/api/JsonServices.php',JSON.stringify(obj),
    new RequestOptions(headers: headers))
```

see also

- https://angular.io/api/http/Http#post
- https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions#headers

Comment: I have updated my code but it's showing error like:"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at url. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
ERROR 
Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: {…}, type: 3, url: null }

Comment: postContactUsData(){

let obj = {id:'78dfak98s'};
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this.http.post('url',JSON.stringify(obj),options)
  .map((res:Response) => res.json());

}

Comment: Can you please help me this one

Comment: CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin error is your server not responding with the expected response headers on the preflight request and the browser therefore refusing to make the actual request. You need to configure your server to support CORS requests. This is one of the most FAQ, therefore it should be easy to find answers. It's not related to Angular in any way, but pure service configuration.

Comment: Thanks,i have understand, issue is service configuration

Answer (score 0):

headers is only one of the options of the http request. Try using RequestOptions

```
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/router';

getContactData(aplhaNumericId:any){
    let obj = {aplhaNumericId:aplhaNumericId};
    let headers=new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf=8');
    // add this 
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
enter code here
    return this.http.post('http://ip/ex/api/api/JsonServices.php', JSON.stringify(obj), options))
        .map((res:Response) => res.json());
}
```

Note this is for the old HttpModule